# Hide Status bar in Windows Phone 8.1 Universal Apps

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

How to hide the Status bar in `Windows Phone 8.1` (C#, XAML)?

In `Windows Phone 8` it was done by setting `shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False"` at any page. But its not available in `Windows Phone 8.1`

Comment: You're confusing Windows Phone 8.1 and Universal Apps.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

With the release of Windows Phone 8.1 SDK comes a new StatusBar. The StatusBar replaces the SystemTray from Windows Phone Silverlight Apps. Unlike the SystemTray, the StausBar can only be accessed via code and some functionality has changed.

```
StatusBar statusBar = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView();

// Hide the status bar
await statusBar.HideAsync();

//Show the status bar
await statusBar.ShowAsync();
```

Reference: [Differences between the new StatusBar in Windows Phone XAML Apps and the SystemTray](http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2014/04/07/Differences-between-the-new-StatusBar-in-Windows-Phone-XAML-Apps-and-the-SystemTray.aspx)

Msdn Reference: [StatusBar class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.ui.viewmanagement.statusbar(v=win.10).aspx)

Comment: Will HideAsync clear ProgressIndicator state?
I.e. Text and Value?

Comment: I think no it just hide the control. You need to clear Text and value explicitely

Answer (score 7):

```
await Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().HideAsync(); 
await Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().ShowAsync();
```

for hiding and showing the system tray

Answer (score 0):

**Here a simple tutorial that explains, working with the Status bar.**

http://denilparmar.blogspot.in/2016/01/working-with-statusbar-in-windows-phone.html

Hope that helps you :-)