# Is it possible to force Windows Phone 8.1 apps to run full screen, hiding the notification bar (aka System Tray)?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I'm not sure of the correct terminology here, but it's the bar at the top of the screen I'm interested in hiding.

I see examples for Windows Phone 8 outlining the following:

```
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
Shell:SystemTray.IsVisiable="False" (Or true to display the tray)
Shell:SystemTray.BackgroundColor="Transparent"
```

But that doesn't work in 8.1.

How can I achieve this in Windows Phone 8.1?

Comment: Here's a great article about making it a behavior so it's reusable and cool. http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2014/04/08/Creating-a-behavior-to-control-the-new-StatusBar-(SystemTray)-in-Windows-Phone-81-XAML-apps.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can try to hide [StatusBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.statusbar(v=win.10).aspx) in App.xaml.cs - for example after activating window:

```
Window.Current.Activate();
StatusBar status = StatusBar.GetForCurrentView();
status.HideAsync();
```

Somehow similar question you will also find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23009501/2681948) with nice reference.