# Hide status bar in Windows Phone 8.1 with XAML

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, expression-blend

I'm trying to hide status bar in Windows Phone 8.1. I see a thread to do this ([Hide Status bar in Windows Phone 8.1 Universal Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23009501/hide-status-bar-in-windows-phone-8-1-universal-apps/29699911)), but this is C#. I would like to hide this status bar in XAML. Reason is that Expression doesn't detect the code in class constructor. When I launch the app all is working, but in Blend it still display the status bar, and so I can't make correctly the design...

My question is : Is there a way to hide status bar in XAML (via a property in Page tag or other) ? Or it is possible to force Blend to detect whatever I write in constructor ?

Thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to hide the status bar in XAML.
But you can hide it in Expression Blend.

Look to the Device Tab and then unselect the Show Status Bar tick as shown in the picture.

[image]