# Suppress System Overlays, Windows phone 8.1 (Silverlight)

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, overlay

I wanted to know how to hide the navigation-bar.
And if it is possible to specify in XAML the code to `SuppressSystemOverlay`, as it is with the systemtray : `shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False"`.

I cannot find the description not even on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.suppresssystemoverlays.aspx), which seems to refer to wp 8.1 build with WinRT, and my application is with silverlight.

Comment: Silverlight is getting to be pretty stale.  [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23009501/hide-status-bar-in-windows-phone-8-1-universal-apps).

Answer (score 3):

The answer is NO, sorry. From 8.1 it is only possible through code as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23009501/hide-status-bar-in-windows-phone-8-1-universal-apps#23009689). However, executing hide code in the constructor like this should give a similar effect:

```
public MainPage()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   await Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().HideAsync();
   Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SuppressSystemOverlays = true;
}
```

Comment: So this is only working on winRT and not silverlight, as per the question.

Comment: I have tried the code and the `Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar` does not exist and also `Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView` does not exist either am I missing something?

Comment: Creating a blank new wp8.1 silverlight still does not have the possibility. Further the post describes the function in relation to WinRT and not silverlight

Comment: And also this links supports my comments http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amar/archive/2014/05/12/status-bar-systemtray-for-silverlight-apps-for-windows-phone-8-1.aspx

Comment: Suit yourself I Will upvote correct answers and mark them answered. I could downvote wring answers not related to the question. If I have or not I will not comment. But you have received a lot of points for not a correct answer so relax and rise to the challenge in stead as me and others. :)