# Grid control can't cover the whole page and leaves a space at the top

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have a default grid control defined in xaml:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

And this grid does not start from the top of the page as you can see from the picture below:

[image]

One way to achieve this is to set a negative margin like this:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid Margin="0,-26.667,0,0">

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

So it will look like in this picture:

[image]

However, I've watched some of Bob Tabor's videos like [this one](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-us/training-courses/windows-phone-8-1-development-for-absolute-beginners-8375?l=xWYccAIz_3504984382) and all of his default controls starts right from the top of the page.

What is the problem here and how can I solve it without setting a negative margin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well status bar is there by default.
You have 2 options:

1. Hide it -> [Hide Status bar in Windows Phone 8.1 Universal Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23009501/hide-status-bar-in-windows-phone-8-1-universal-apps)
2. put your content under it:

`var applicationView = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
applicationView.SetDesiredBoundsMode(Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewBoundsMode.UseCoreWindow);`

You may wish to read this for additional info:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amar/archive/2014/05/12/status-bar-in-windows-phone-8-1.aspx

Comment: I will mark this as an answer, although it is not an elegant solution. I have to hide Status bar from code behind so I have no idea how the overall design would look like during the process of styling my app.